# Getting Stripe axios error code bad response with post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, stripe-payments

Backend code for the payment gateway. Please help me out in this. I'm trying to test if I'm getting any

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

router.post("/payment", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await stripe.charges.create(
      {
        source: req.body.tokenId,
        amount: req.body.amount,
        currency: "usd"
      },
      (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
        if (stripeErr) {
          res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
        } else {
          res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import axios from "axios";

const KEY =
  "pk_test_51NHAjsKz9UEAUpd2Thxt2GmJSBC9PH9Uv9i4pI399srbET7pPgMUZn8NMPicAxqtgYwvOInpDq5vUwz5V9qRHJID00EQLVvW5F";
const Pay = () => {
  const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null);
  const onToken = (token) => {
    setStripeToken(token);
    console.log(token);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/checkout/payment",
          {
            tokenId: stripeToken.id,
            amount: 2000,
          }
        );
        console.log(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  }, [stripeToken]);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <StripeCheckout
        name="ludweig"
        image="https://fakestoreapi.com/img/61U7T1koQqL._AC_SX679_.jpg"
        billingAddress
        shippingAddress
        description="Your Total is $20"
        amount={2000}
        token={onToken}
        stripeKey={KEY}
      >
        <button
          style={{
            border: "none",
            width: 120,
            borderRadius: 5,
            padding: "20px",
            backgroundColor: "black",
            color: "white",
          }}
        >
          Pay Now
        </button>
      </StripeCheckout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pay;
```

This is my frontend code to test if i'm receiving response from backend when i send the request but im getting Axios error of bad response "internal server error". I have searched the internet and got this that it is because of server, but im testing it on localhost.

Below are my logs from stripe dashboard. see if it could help in understanding the error i'm getting. I have also updated my backend code with async await as suggested by someone

```
{
  "id": "tok_1NM4gUKz9UEAUpd2Tz4bv9Hc",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_1NM4gUKz9UEAUpd22GnpMrkU",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": "khi",
    "address_country": "Pakistan",
    "address_line1": "demo",
    "address_line1_check": "unchecked",
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": "demo",
    "address_zip_check": "unchecked",
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "cvc_check": "unchecked",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 8,
    "exp_year": 2028,
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "4242",
    "name": "demo",
    "tokenization_method": null,
    "wallet": null
  },
  "client_ip": "111.88.172.184",
  "created": 1687506334,
  "email": "demo@gmail.com",
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
Request POST body
{
  "referrer": "http://localhost:3000/pay",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  "key": "pk_test_*********************************************************************************************LVvW5F",
  "device_id": "7cb8b987-7352-4192-9011-2d30428dea7e",
  "sid": "ce36cd4a-0235-467b-a75c-e4e681716755dbb6e7",
  "validation_type": "card",
  "time_checkout_loaded": "1687506288",
  "time_checkout_opened": "1687506289",
  "payment_user_agent": "Stripe Checkout v3 (stripe.js/78ef418)",
  "card": {
    "number": "************4242",
    "exp_month": "8",
    "address_country": "Pakistan",
    "cvc": "***",
    "exp_year": "2028",
    "address_line1": "demo",
    "address_zip": "demo",
    "address_city": "khi",
    "name": "demo"
  },
  "muid": "3243490b-653f-4185-bf9f-6a8c7e2d058deb0980",
  "pasted_fields": "number",
  "email": "demo@gmail.com",
  "guid": "f0c821bc-8bea-4111-8e83-095aeb31cc33d575cb",
  "time_on_page": "43260"
}
```

Finally after consoling the stripe error i'm receiving stripe api key error but i already have the secret key in my .env file and public key in frontend code but still getting the error that stripe needs the api key in authorization header.

```
Stripe error StripeAuthenticationError: You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.
    at res.toJSON.then.Error_js_1.StripeAPIError.message (G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\stripe\cjs\RequestSender.js:96:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'StripeAuthenticationError',
  raw: {
    message: "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.",      
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Fri, 23 Jun 2023 08:02:56 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '342',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="Stripe"',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 401,
    requestId: undefined
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: undefined,
  doc_url: undefined,
  param: undefined,
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Fri, 23 Jun 2023 08:02:56 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '342',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="Stripe"',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  requestId: undefined,
  statusCode: 401,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}
```

**UPDATE**
It's working now when i provided the secret key in the main file, as if it was not picking up from .env file. What could be the problem. HELP

Comment: is the only code you have written on server side? kindly do share error logs as well as descriptive code for server, thereby, I can see what you did mistake on server code.

Comment: instead of using callback in stripe do use async/await with try catch

Comment: You're adding `stripeErr` to the response so what does it say? Instead of `console.log(error)`, try `console.error(error.response?.data)`. I would also strongly advise adding server-side error logging as well, eg `console.error("Stripe error", stripeErr); res.status(500).json(stripeErr);`

Answer (score -1):

"internal server error" usually means something went wrong in your server. You shall check your server log and Stripe Dashboard [log](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs) and see what happened.